# How to upload youtube video? Cron in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, youtube, cron

I want to upload the video to my youtube account from my `cron job` created in `php`. But this is not possible as the `oauth` requires user intervention for allowing the access every time and the samples found in the api documentation does not provide any clues for getting this done. Can anybody please help me to get this done?